# which AWS service is should I use for email verification after signup

Tags: python, email, django

I have a Django app that sends emails over smtp for users after signing up process is completed, but I am confused about my use-case, what service of AWS should I use, what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

[AWS SES](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/) is your choice. But in order to send emails to unverified (unknown) addresses, you need [to move out of sandbox mode](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/request-production-access.html).